# I can't seem to find a way to check if a email has been taken in my mysql db (php7)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created a php7 and mySQL website that lets users login and register to a site.

I have made sure that the user cannot use the same username as someone else that has signed up, but I cannot seem to do the same with the emails.

I made my website so when the signup button is pressed, the browser directs to a file called signup.inc.php. I don'tknow what to change or how to fix it,I have been searching for a solution and I am pretty stuck on this problem, so help would be nice :)

The part I am focusing on is:

```
if ($resultCheck > 0) {
          header("Location: ../signup.php?error=emailtaken");
          exit();
```

this also includes the working user checker:

```
  else {
    $sql = "SELECT uidUsers AND emailUsers FROM users WHERE uidUsers=? AND emailUsers=?";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
      header("Location: ../signup.php?error=sqlerror");
      exit();
    }
    else{
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $username, $email);
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
      mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
      $resultCheck = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
      if ($resultCheck > 0) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=usertaken");
        exit();
      }
      else{
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $email);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
        $resultCheck = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
        if ($resultCheck > 0) {
          header("Location: ../signup.php?error=emailtaken");
          exit();
        }
```

I tried a few things to get it to work that is maybe why it is messy, but I cannot seem to get the check of the email in the database to work. It says on my website "signup success" but what it should say is "email taken". Any help?
Here is the full page for reference:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['signup-submit'])){
  require 'dbh.inc.php';

  $username = $_POST['uid'];
  $email = $_POST['mail'];
  $password = $_POST['pwd'];
  $passwordRepeat = $_POST['pwd-repeat'];

  if (empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password) || empty($passwordRepeat)) {
    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=emptyfields&uid=".$username."&mail=".$email);
    exit();
  }
  else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username)) {
    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invalidmailuid");
    exit();
  }
  else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invalidmail&uid=".$username);
    exit();
  }
  else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username)) {
    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invaliduid&mail=".$email);
    exit();
  }
  else if($password !== $passwordRepeat){
    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=passwordcheck&uid=".$username."&mail=".$email);
    exit();
  }
  else {
    $sql = "SELECT uidUsers AND emailUsers FROM users WHERE uidUsers=? AND emailUsers=?";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
      header("Location: ../signup.php?error=sqlerror");
      exit();
    }
    else{
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $username, $email);
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
      mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
      $resultCheck = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
      if ($resultCheck > 0) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=usertaken");
        exit();
      }
      else{
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $email);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
        $resultCheck = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
        if ($resultCheck > 0) {
          header("Location: ../signup.php?error=emailtaken");
          exit();
        }
        else {
        //other
          $sql = "INSERT INTO users (uidUsers, emailUsers, pwdUsers) VALUES (?, ?, ?) ";
          $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
          if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            header("Location: ../signup.php?error=sqlerror");
            exit();
          }
          else {
            $hashedPwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $username, $email, $hashedPwd);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            header("Location: ../index.php?signup=success");
            exit();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  msqli_stmt_close($stmt);
  msqli_close($conn);
}
else {
  header("Location: ../signup.php");
  exit();
}
```

I tried bug fixing, looking for a solution, and trying to do the same as the username but idk

I wanted emails to be not repeated, but on my website, it says 'login success' which is wrong.

Comment: Instead of `uidUsers=? AND emailUsers=?` try `uidUsers=? OR emailUsers=?`. When it works, look for an UNION ALL optimization.

Comment: Your solution isn't bulletproof. Unless username and email are made unique in the database, you can get multiple people registering using the same info if they submit the data at nearly the same time. +1 for using prepared statements.

Comment: how would go about making them unique in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happening because of an 'AND' condition in your SQL where clause. Validate only username Column to check for exists. 
In your implementation, it is checking the combination of email and username for duplicates. 
If you want to validate either of the columns, use an 'OR' In your where clause.

Comment: frick yeee thanks man :) it worked. I am new to php so don't blame me for being a noob. Thanks for helping me out and have a nice day!

Comment: @DMMOfficial If it answers your question, consider to [formally accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.